# Как написать функцию расчета процентов в калькуляторе на Python?

Tags: python

GUI Калькулятор. Не пойму как написать функцию расчета процентов при делении. Т.е. 50 / 5% = 20, но  у меня не выводится 20, а выводится 1000. Уже по-разному делаю, и так, и сяк, либо 1000 выводит, либо 0.1 Кто может помочь, как эту функцию правильно написать?

Comment: Хотелось бы понять - что это за арифметика: "50 / 5% = 20" ?

Comment: `50 / 5% = 20`, `100 / 5% = 20`, `1 / 5% = 20`. К чему в этом выражении первое число, раз от него ничего не зависит?

Answer (score 3):

Может быть, что вы выражением

```
50 / 5%
```

имеете в виду

```
50 / (5% из 50)
```

что в результате действительно выдает `20`.

В том случае надо знать, что такой результат будет *всегда, вне зависимости от первого числа,* потому что для любого числа `x` будет

```
x / (5% из x) = x / ((5/100) * x) = 1 / (5/100) = 100 / 5 = 20
```

Значит, ваш калькулятор должен для какого-либо процента `p%` выводить число `100 / p`.

Answer (score 0):

% в пайтон используется не как процент а остаток отделения. попробуйте:

```
50 * (5 / 100)
```

Причём это не 20 а 2,5.

Comment: 50 / 5% это 20 либо 1000.